# Problems with the scaling on html/css website

Tags: html, css

so i've tried to make this website the past two days with my friend. Everyone has been going smooth and we have gotten a lot of help from here. Though we are having a problem about the scaling on the website. When our website is in fullscreen everything is okay but if you have the window open so that it only covers half the monitor there is a white block under the website. 
You can see what i mean here: https://gyazo.com/103cf6b312512a2ce9fdac7e23788fdf
Thank you

```css
 <style>
.Button {
    background-color: Plum;
    border: 1px solid;
 border-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
 font-family: hacked;
 border-radius: 8px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
 
 
}

  .sub {
  position: relative;
}
.itmHolder {
  position: relative;
}

  
  
  .itmHolder:nth-child(2),
.itmHolder:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.og {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 400%;
 color: Plum;
 text-shadow: 4px 4px Black;
}
body {  
    background-image: url("lightning.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}


 </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Our Future</title>
 </head>
 
 <body background="lightning.gif">
 
 <embed name="myMusic" loop="true" hidden="true" src="thunder.mp3"></embed>


     <center><h1 style="font-family:blowbrush;">Future</center></h1><form action="side2.html">
  
  
   <div class="og">
  <div class="itmHolder">

  <div class="sub">
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="side2.html">About us</a></button>
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="buynow.html">Buy now</a></button>
    </div>
  
  
  
  <br></br>
 </body>
</html>
  <picture>
  <!--Billede-->
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
 <center><img src="ourfuture.png" alt="Matrix" width="700" height="400" border="5"><center/>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `min-height: 100vh` to `body` so it extends to the bottom of the window if the content is shorter than the browser viewport. You might also add `margin: 0` so the default margin doesn't make the window vertically scroll if the browser is taller than the content.

```css
 <style>
.Button {
    background-color: Plum;
    border: 1px solid;
 border-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
 font-family: hacked;
 border-radius: 8px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
 
 
}

  .sub {
  position: relative;
}
.itmHolder {
  position: relative;
}

  
  
  .itmHolder:nth-child(2),
.itmHolder:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.og {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 400%;
 color: Plum;
 text-shadow: 4px 4px Black;
}
body {  
    background-image: url("http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
   min-height: 100vh;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}


 </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Our Future</title>
 </head>
 
 <body background="lightning.gif">
 
 <embed name="myMusic" loop="true" hidden="true" src="thunder.mp3"></embed>


     <center><h1 style="font-family:blowbrush;">Future</center></h1><form action="side2.html">
  
  
   <div class="og">
  <div class="itmHolder">

  <div class="sub">
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="side2.html">About us</a></button>
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="buynow.html">Buy now</a></button>
    </div>
  
  
  
  <br></br>
 </body>
</html>
  <picture>
  <!--Billede-->
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
 <center><img src="ourfuture.png" alt="Matrix" width="700" height="400" border="5"><center/>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>
</picture>
```

Comment: @EmalGod you bet :)